# Multiple html select in asp.net NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, exception

I am using a multiple select html control in my asp.net project and I am trying to get the selected items by te user. This is my html code used in .aspx web page:

```
<label>Drop Columns: </label>
<select id="select1" name="select1" runat="server" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple">
  <option value=0>Rows Header</option>
  <option value=1>item 1</option>
  <option value=2>item 2</option>
  <option value=3>item 3</option>
  <option value=4>item 3</option>
</select>
```

and this is the C# code behind used to get the selected items by the user:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= select1.Items.Count -1; i++)
{
     if (select1.Items[i].Selected)
     {
          test = select1.Items[i].ToString();
     }
 }
```

when I execute my code I get an `NullReferenceException` in `select1.Items.Count` on which: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

what is the problem?

Comment: "test" is defined and assigned any default values?

Comment: defined in a previous part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected value like:

```
test = Request.Form["select1"];
```

Comment: Yes. the multiple items will be separated with commas, like: `item 1, item2`

Comment: i check and it works, but I still can't understand why my code doesn't work and throw an exception

Comment: so please upvote and mark as answer. but why your doesn't work, I have no idea as i have never used it that way. and I think having a loop through items while you have it is something extra

Comment: there is nothing extra, `select1.Items.Count` is the instruction that throws the exception

Comment: I know, I say even if you get the list there, why would you loop through all items to get the selected ones while you can have them without looping and using `Request.Form["select1"]`?

Comment: because if I have space in the option value `Request.Form["select1"]` will return only the first word, the others will be neglected, and this is not my case.

Comment: nope, this will only happen if you have comma in value.

Comment: but this just happened with me :'(